# Switch entering wrong case?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

The image below says it all. I'm debugging my android app and this Switch statement is entering the wrong CASE, please see the watches for the values of the variables involved. FYI, HOURLY and WARNING are constants defined like this

```
private static final int CURRENTLY = 0;
private static final int HOURLY = 1;
private static final int DAILY = 2;
private static final int DAY = 3;
private static final int WARNING = 4;
```

[image]

What is going on here :O

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
    @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    DisplayWeatherInfo weatherInfoObject = weatherInfo.get(position);

    if (weatherInfoObject instanceof Currently) {
        return CURRENTLY;
    } else if (weatherInfoObject instanceof Hourly) {
        return HOURLY;
    } else if (weatherInfoObject instanceof Daily) {
        return DAILY;
    } else if (weatherInfoObject instanceof Day) {
        return DAY;
    } else if (weatherInfoObject instanceof Warning) {
        return WARNING;
    }
    return -1;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case CURRENTLY:
            view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.currently_view, parent, false);
            return new CurrentlyViewHolder(view);
        case HOURLY:
            view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.hourly_view, parent, false);
            return new HourlyViewHolder(view);
        case DAILY:
            view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_view, parent, false);
            return new DailyViewHolder(view);
        case DAY:
            view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.day_view, parent, false);
            return new DayViewHolder(view);
        case WARNING:
            view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.warning_view, parent, false);
            return new WarningViewHolder(view);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

GIST for the adapter class: https://gist.github.com/feresr/2183e922b07c450304c5

Comment: I think this is an impossible question to answer without more information. We have no idea why `viewholder.getItemViewType()` should or shouldn't be any particular value.

Comment: Are you sure you are debugging the code you think you are? In my experience, this is caused by stale class files. Please try a clean build.

Comment: Paul:, I updated the question with more code on the adapter, it's really strange. Elliott: Thanks, I will try to rebuild and see what happens.

Comment: @feresr I've had no end of problems with the viewholder pattern. Is it possible you are somehow getting views and viewholders mixed up?

Comment: Unfortunately, a clean build lead to the same results. The odd thing is that this was working before I added the "WARNING" viewHolder.  @Paul, perhaps I am confusing them, but I don't see a problem in my logic, I'm treating this 'Warning' viewHolder just as treat the others. I don't see any reason why the Switch statement should behave this way.

Comment: No, they both extend from DisplayWeatherInfo. :/

Comment: Do you call the appropriate `notify` method every time you change `weatherInfo`?

Comment: Well, I believe I do, I've created a gist so you can see the entire thing.

Comment: @feresr I'm really sorry. I've had a good look through the code and can't see the problem.

Comment: @Paul, check my answer below. Thanks so much for your time. I feel like I'm in doubt now. Don't hesitate to contact me if you ever need something android related and you think I can be on any help. twitter ferRaviola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application was crashing because of a completely different reason, I won't bore you with the details, basically it my fault for using a constant where I shouldn't have. It just so happened that this constant was near this switch statement. Nonetheless the debugging problem seems to be an issue with Android studio 1.4.1, I turned my computer off an on again (IT crowd style) and the issue persisted. I'm not familiar with the process for creating bugs for android studio nor I am sure how to reproduce this consistently so I'm not even sure this is a valid bug. Anyways, I'd like to thank you guys for your time, and sorry to have bothered you. Thanks again for your help!  For those wondering what was wrong:

```
if (day == ((Daily) weatherInfo.get(2)).getDays().get(0)) {
```

That 2 is constant that should be a 3 when the warning is shown.